# How can I figure out in array each element contains a certain word?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to add word in each array elements. But one of the element has that word. That's I want to pass that, and add the word other elements.

Here is my array.

```
string(56) "//sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/bukken/detail/index/id/K4810000"
[1]=>
string(56) "//sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/bukken/detail/index/id/K4780000"
[2]=>
string(56) "//sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/bukken/detail/index/id/K4720000"
[3]=>
string(56) "//sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/bukken/detail/index/id/K4760000"
[4]=>
string(62) "https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/bukken/detail/index/id/K4770000"
[5]=>
string(56) "//sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/bukken/detail/index/id/K4740000"
```

The forth one has `https:` but the other has not. I want to add all `http:` all of them.

```
$http = 'https:';

foreach($iframeLink as $value)
{
    if (!$value contains 'http')
        $iframe[] = $http.$value;
}
```

`Contains` is not working. It's simple thing but I couldn't figure it out. Any help? Thank You!

Comment: The code is php, but your tags contain javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) function. It finds the first occurrence of a given substring within the string. So, if `stripos($value,'https:')` returns `false`; it basically implies that the string `$value` does not contain `'https:'`

```
foreach($iframeLink as $value)
{
    if ( stripos($value,'https:') === false )
        $iframe[] = $http.$value;
}
```

Now, there is a chance `'https:` may exist at other positions in the string. And, you need to prepend `'https:` only when it is not at the beginning of the given string. In that case, you can try the following instead:

```
foreach($iframeLink as $value)
{
    if ( stripos($value,'https:') > 0 )
        $iframe[] = $http.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In laravel there is a helper function `str_contains()`

```
foreach($iframeLink as $value)
{
    if (str_contains($value, 'https:')) $iframe[] = $http.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `substr()` to selecting special part of string and check that is `https` or not.

```
$http = 'https:';
foreach($iframeLink as $key=>$value){
    if (substr($value, 0, 6) != $http)
        $iframe[] = $http.$value;
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/X4gh2)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse URL and check it [scheme](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$http = 'https:';
foreach($iframeLink as $value)
{
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($value);
   if ($parsedUrl['scheme']!='http') {
     $iframe[] = $http.$value;
   }
}
```